# AngularJS, Persistent (header) controller and specific (body) controller in one app

Tags: html, angularjs

I am developing an HTML 5 mobile angular app with an android style skin. The app will need to be login-aware and I'm looking for advice on best practices. What I need is:

1. To have a persistent header that will display the current view, change the current view (via a dropdown), and perform login-specific functions (like "view my stuff" or "logout")
2. To have several different views within the app such as "master view" and "detail view" and "map view"
3. To have the app display a particular view (login.html) when the user is not logged in.

It seems like 3 is a special case of 1. In any case, the header is persistent throughout the app (except when a user isn't logged in) and the views will change based on user input. What is the best way to tackle this style of application using angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude).

I think you're already using `ng-view` for your body. Makes things easy :

```
<body>
  <div id="header" ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
  <div id="container" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes but I also need to be able to observe the controller in my app. I will rephrase my question in case.